# drop list from field to execute SQL request

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-script-tool, tool-validation

I'm trying to create a python script that allows a selection attribute based on the name of a field in the attribute table of a layer.

I would like to configure my script such a way that permits the user to select the `SOURCE NAME` from a drop-down list.
Here's the code I have written:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = 'in_memory'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True 
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
PosteLayer=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
field="NAME_SOURCE"
rows=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(PosteLayer,["NAME_SOURCE"])
list=[]
for row in rows:
   if str(row[O]) not in list:
       liste.append(row[0])
POSTES=liste
POSTES=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
```

I'm using the Advanced Version Of Arcgis 10.2

Comment: You need to look into tool validation on a Python Script tool.

Comment: @PolyGeo what can i add in my case 
i never work with the tool validation before

Comment: Whenever I need to do it I go to the Help to re-learn how.

Comment: that's what i have done already before posting this 
i really need help

Comment: Here is an example that uses the Python Toolbox. I find it a little easier to use validation in that context than the tbx. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82473/generating-a-multivalue-choice-list-in-arcgis-using-validation-not-availalbe-fo

Answer (score 1):

First: you should make a toolbox with a script set the parameters the name "List of Source Name" the data type "string" the filter "value list as in picture:
[image]

Second: select Validation the edit button write under the (def updateParameters(self)) the following:

```
def updateParameters(self):

        #define the path of your feature class
        fc="D:/000/test.shp"
        #define the the name of the field
        col=  ("SOURCENAME")
        self.params[0].filter.list = [str(val) for val in  
                                        sorted(  
                                          set(  
                                            row.getValue(col)  
                                            for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(fc, None, None,col)))]  
        if self.params[0].value not in self.params[0].filter.list:  
          self.params[0].value = self.params[0].filter.list[0]
        return
```

Third: create a tool script and write the following:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
currentlayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*") [0]
inputLayer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(currentlayer)  
TWN = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
query  = "SOURCENAME = '" + TWN + "'"
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(currentlayer, "NEW_SELECTION",  query )
count = arcpy.GetCount_management(currentlayer)
arcpy.AddMessage("thes selected are:  "+str(count))
```

or you can write in the validation script the following:

```
def updateParameters(self):
    #define the top layer in the mapview
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    fc = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*") [0]

    #define the the name of the field
    col=  ("SOURCENAME")
    self.params[0].filter.list = [str(val) for val in  
                                    sorted(  
                                      set(  
                                        row.getValue(col)  
                                        for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(fc, None, None,col)))]  
    if self.params[0].value not in self.params[0].filter.list:  
      self.params[0].value = self.params[0].filter.list[0]
    return
```